# Tool for exporting html as pdf

Tags: php, html, pdf, export

I have a html document which marks up a report. I have a button on this page "Export as pdf". However I am not sure how to export html into a pdf..Are there any tools out there that anyone recommends for such a task..

EDIT: In more detail:

I have the following php:

```
<?php

function connect() {
  $dbh = mysql_connect ("localhost", "user", "password") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("PDS", $dbh); 
  return $dbh;
}

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
  if(isset($_POST['entryId'])){
    //do something
    $dbh = connect();
    $ide = $_POST['entryId'];
    $usertab = $_POST['usertable'];
    $answertable = $usertab . "Answers";
    $entrytable = $usertab . "Entries";
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT e.date, q.questionNumber, q.question, q.sectionId, a.answer FROM $answertable a, Questions q, $entrytable e WHERE a.entryId = '$ide' AND a.questionId = q.questionId AND e.entryId = '$ide' ORDER BY q.questionNumber ASC;") or die("Error: " . mysql_error());

    if($query){
      //set variables

      $sectionOne = array();
      $sectionTwo = array();
      $sectionThree = array();
      $sectionFour = array();
      $sectionFive = array();
      while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $date = $row['date'];
    $section = $row['sectionId'];
    switch($section){
    case '1':
      $sectionOne[] = $row;
      break;
    case '2':
      $sectionTwo[] = $row;
      break;
    case '3':
      $sectionThree[] = $row;
      break;
        case '4':
      $sectionFour[] = $row;
      break;
        case '5':
      $sectionFive[] = $row;
      break;
        default:    
      break;      
    }
      }
    }else{
      //error - sql failed
    }
  }

?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
   <script src = "jQuery.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){

   });
  </script>
  <title>Personal Diary System - Entry Report - <?php echo($date); ?></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Entry Report - <?php echo($date); ?></h1>    
  <div id = "buttons">
  <a href = "http://dev.speechlink.co.uk">Export as PDF</a>                       
  </div>                         
  <h3>Biological Information</h3>
  <?php
      $i = 0;                         
      foreach($sectionOne as &$value){
    if($i == 1 || $i == 3){
      $image = "assets/urine".$i.".png";
      echo("<br/>");
      echo($value['question']." <br/> "."<img src = \"$image\"/>");
      echo("<br/>");
    }else{
      echo($value['question'].' : '.$value['answer']);
    }
    echo("<br/>");
    $i++;
      }
  ?>
  <h3>Fatigue and Recovery</h3>
  <?php
      foreach($sectionTwo as &$value){
    echo($value['question'].' : '.$value['answer']);
    echo("<br/>");
      }
  ?>
  <h3>Illness and Injury</h3>
  <?php
      foreach($sectionThree as &$value){
    echo($value['question'].' : '.$value['answer']);
    echo("<br/>");
      }
  ?>
  <h3>Training Sessions</h3>
  <?php
      foreach($sectionFour as &$value){
    echo($value['question'].' : '.$value['answer']);
    echo("<br/>");
      }
  ?>
  <h3>General Feedback</h3>
  <?php 
     if(count($sectionFive)>0){
      foreach($sectionFive as &$value){
    echo($value['question'].' : '.$value['answer']);    
      }
     }else{
       echo("User didn't leave any feedback");
     }
     echo("<br/>");
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

This displays the following:

[image]

So if I'm using fpdf, what is the best way to export the following as a pdf? Should I write a fpdf function in the same php file or is it best to write a separate php file which creates and displays the pdf (which means I would have to post all relevant data to this file)...

Comment: On what platform? With a GUI or scriptable? Using what technologies?

Comment: The one way that I know is that install a pdf printer on your system to print you html pages as pdf.

Comment: Consult our handy [list of HTML to PDF converters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178448/list-of-html-to-pdf-converters)

Answer (score 6):

Use FPDF library for php
[check here](http://fpdf.org/)

The first and the main base for this file conversion is FPDF library. FPDF is a pure PHP class to generate PDF files on the fly. Let us start the PDF generation with a simple Hello world display.

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

To generate a pdf file, first we need to include library file fpdf.php. Then we need to create an FPDF object using the default constructor FPDF(). This constructor can be passed three values namely page orientation (portrait or landscape), measure unit, and page size (A4, A5, etc.,). By default pages are in A4 portrait and the measure unit is millimeter. It could have been specified explicitly with:

```
$pdf=new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
```

It is possible to use landscape (L), other page formats (such as Letter and Legal) and measure units (pt, cm, in).

Then we have added a page to our pdf document with AddPage(). The origin is at the upper-left corner and the current position is by default placed at 1 cm from the borders; the margins can be changed with the function SetMargins().

To print a text, we need to first select a font with SetFont(). Let us select Arial bold 16:

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
```

We use Cell() function to output a text. A cell is a rectangular area, possibly framed, which contains some text. It is output at the current position. We specify its dimensions, its text (centered or aligned), if borders should be drawn, and where the current position moves after it (to the right, below or to the beginning of the next line). To add a frame, we would do this:

```
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World !',1);
```

Finally, the document is closed and sent to the browser with Output(). We could have saved it in a file by passing the desired file name.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this software quite useful: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

It is true that you'll have to exec() it from your code, but it works very good and uses webkit as the backend engine (allowing javascript also, and many other features to customize the pdf creation), saving a *lot* of code.

Hope it helps, we're using it here and it works like a charm.

EDIT: try the static binaries. untar and ready to go :)

Answer (score 1):

You may also use an online tool *Pdfcrowd API*

Its easy to integrate and provides much in its free edition. You may check 
[PDFCrowd Official Site](http://pdfcrowd.com/i/how-to-export-html-to-pdf-with-php.html)

```
 require 'pdfcrowd.php';

// create an API client instance
$client = new Pdfcrowd("username", "apikey");

// convert a web page and store the generated PDF into a variable
$pdf = $client->convertURI('http://www.google.com/');

//You can also convert raw HTML code, just use the convertHtml() method instead of convertURI()
$pdf = $client->convertHtml("<body>My HTML Layout</body>");

//Or use convertFile() to convert a local HTML file
$pdf = $client->convertFile("/path/to/MyLayout.html");


// set HTTP response headers
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Accept-Ranges: none");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"google_com.pdf\"");

// send the generated PDF 
echo $pdf;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another much easier way is with HTML2FPDF.
HTML2FPDF is a PHP Class library that uses the FPDF class library to convert HTML files to PDF files. This library consist of three classes namely PDF, HTML2FPDF and FPDF (modified FPDF class). The class PDF extends the class HTML2FPDF that extends the class FPDF.

Now let us see, how to convert a sample html page into a PDF file using HTML2FPDF Library. The html page contains a table that lists a few nations with their corresponding national flags. Below is the code for the conversion.

```
<?
require('html2fpdf.php');
$pdf=new HTML2FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$fp = fopen("sample.html","r");
$strContent = fread($fp, filesize("sample.html"));
fclose($fp);
$pdf->WriteHTML($strContent);
$pdf->Output("sample.pdf");
echo "PDF file is generated successfully!";
?>
```

First, we need to include the html2fpdf.php file that contains the HTML2FPDF class and an object is created using the constructor HTML2FPDF(). Then a new page is added to the pdf document using the function AddPage(). The html contents are read from the sample.html file using file functions. Then the html contents are written in to the pdf format using WriteHTML() function. To view the html file, click here and to view the generated pdf, click here. The above sample code with the sample html file and images and the html2fpdf class libraries can be downloaded here.

The HTML2FPDF class library will be working best with the XHTML 1.0. Also the class does not support all the features available with HTML. To know the supported HTML tags and other features, Please refer http://html2fpdf.sourceforge.net.

I recommend you to use this since it's much easier and friendly.