# Export a html into PDF in PHP?

Tags: php, html, pdf, export

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

What's the fastest, cleanest and best way to export from PHP a webpage (given URL) into PDF?

Comment: @Ervin: Please use the search before asking a question. This has been asked before.

Answer (score 4):

Hard. You wont be able to *convert* HTML to PDF *just like that* without any manipulation. One shot may be using [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/), but that probabliy won't satisfy your needs, since it has limited HTML functionality.

The other way would be making a screenshot of a webpage and including it in PDF document, but you'll need specialized software, or at least libray. [Read further on that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php).

Answer (score 2):

You can go for [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/).

Answer (score 2):

dompdf is an HTML to PDF converter. At its heart, dompdf is (mostly) CSS 2.1 compliant HTML layout and rendering engine written in PHP [domPdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)