# Export text from web site to pdf

Tags: pdf, web, export-to-pdf

Hello can you tell me how can I export website text to Acrobat reader. I need button which will generate acrobat reader file. thanks

Comment: Two different approaches: a headless browser with a pdf renderer or pseudo printer (you will find lots of links on gogole for that) or a programmatical approach: you generate a document by using one of the many php creation solutions (see google again) and render the same content used to generate the html page. Depends a little on what content you have. Unfortunately the question is far too broad for this place here, this place is for _specific programming questions_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use browser addon for export as PDF.
other wise u have to write a code.
read this..
this will help u
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11833803/3184640

Answer (score 0):

Install DoPDF [from here](http://www.dopdf.com) and then click on File->Print and instead of printing to a normal physical printer, you can "print" into a PDF file.