# Export to excel and pdf using php

Tags: php

How can I create  web based software based on PHP in which there are two functionalities.

1. Export to excel
2. Export to PDF

I am using two languages - English and Kannada .. help me to solve this query.

Comment: This question is too broad. Could you please first share what you have tried.

Answer (score -1):

I have not enough point to add a comment. By the way try to look here, it can helps you: PDF [PDF Export in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496122/pdf-export-in-php)

Comment: what about export to excel